# New users should be redirected to the proper site instead of being downvoted

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, new-users, off-topic

New users (like me) use to post questions on any Stack Exchange site, and sometimes they are closed as off-topic and get lots of down votes which is quite demotivating for those users, causing them to avoid asking questions.

Instead, they should be redirected to the relevant site, so that they are not demotivated and they will know where to ask the question.

Comment: Question is very poorly asked, but I'll edit it to demonstrate how it should have been asked instead of just downvoting so you won't be demotivated.

Comment: Are you talking about automatic redirection? Or something else? Not clear from the question.

Comment: If the question is on-topic on *some* sites, then that's salvageable: users can generously suggest these sites on comment. Even for questions that unexpectedly good quality can be migrated. But what about a question that is purely off-topic on all sites? Redirect to how-to-ask?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes, generally off topics are based on some conditions I think, So instead of making it off topic those users can redirect that question.

Comment: @AndrewT. if the question is completely off topic on all website then there is no need of migrating but if it is possible then simply migrate it because for a new user/beginner it will take time for him to understand where to ask the question.

Comment: Plenty of new users don't post off topic questions.  Can you explain why you disregarded all the information provided to you as to what is and is not topic?

Comment: Can you shows us some example questions? So we can see more clearly what the issue is.

Answer (score 16):

While I can understand it being demotivating if you post on the wrong site, there are pointers for you:

1. Each site has a tour section which gives help and an indication of what is on topic for that site.
   In my observation of first posts on various sites, I think you are more likely to receive downvotes if you don't have the Informed badge than if you do.
2. It doesn't take long to look at a few questions on the site to see if there is something similar already posted.

I don't think it is necessary to add any other feature to try to direct people to which site is relevant.